# static file not loading in spring boot for web-secure-jdbc

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring boot web secure jdbc sample *spring-boot-sample-web-secure-jdbc* and want to modify it to load static html files (no template like thymeleaf or jsp needed).  I have tried putting the html files under src/main/resources but they are not loading.

I noticed that static file example in samples *spring-boot-sample-web-static* inherits SpringBootServletInitializer for main class while web secure jdbc use WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.  I suppose there might be some more configuration needed to make it work them.  Below is my dir tree:

```
src/main/java/hello/MyController.java
src/main/resources/backupshell.html
src/main/resources/myscripts.js
```

After moving resources to src/main/resources/resources direct url load works fine but via request url mapping as below is not loading:

```
 @RequestMapping("/admin")
    //@ResponseBody
    String admin() {
        //return "Hello World admin!";
        return "backupshell";
    }
```

and logs snippet is as below:

```
2016-04-18 16:16:51.716 DEBUG 8896 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/backupshell] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@7a9c84a5]]] and 1 interceptor
2016-04-18 16:16:51.716 DEBUG 8896 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/backupshell] is: -1
2016-04-18 16:16:51.717 DEBUG 8896 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-04-18 16:16:51.717 DEBUG 8896 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2016-04-18 16:16:51.718 DEBUG 8896 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2016-04-18 16:16:51.718 DEBUG 8896 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@24880cb8
2016-04-18 16:16:51.718 DEBUG 8896 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2016-04-18 16:16:51.720 DEBUG 8896 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
```

Regards,

Miten.

Comment: put it in a `static` or `public` directory in `src/main/resources/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root resource directory `src/main/resources/` isn't exposed publicly. As described in [this post](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) there are 4 directories which are automatically loaded by Spring Boot to serve static content:

1. /public/
2. /static/
3. /resources/
4. /META-INF/resources/

In your case you can put the HTML and the JS file inside ,e.g., the `/public` directory:

```
src/main/resources/public/backupshell.html
src/main/resources/public/myscripts.js
```

Then you can access the files with the address of your application, with default configuration it would be:

```
localhost:8080/backupshell.html
```

Note that 3rd option `/resource/` doesn't mean that `src/main/resources/` is exposed. It's the `src/main/resources/resources/` directory, which can feel quite cumbersome.

Comment: your reply is correct.  I have moved to src/main/resources/resources and used above url and it locates all resources fine but spring method mapped for /admin that returns "backupshell" is not able to resolve the same.